# Proof that $X^n+1$ is divisible by $X+1$ if $n$ is odd.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have to proof that $X^n+1$ is divisible by $X+1$ if $n$ is odd ($n\in\mathbb N$). If $n$ is odd, that means that $n=2m+1$ ($m\in\mathbb N_0$).
I was using full induction.

**Base**: If $m=0$ then $X^{2m+1}+1$ is $X^1+1$, which is divisible by $X+1.$

**Assumption**: $X^{2m+1}+1$ is divisible by $X+1$, true.

**Step**: I set $m$ to $m+1$, which means I get $X^{2(m+1)+1}+1$ which equals $X^{2m+3}+1$. And that's the point where I'm having trouble. I tried several ways to split it up, but I never got it in a way so that I could use the assumption for the entire equation, just for a few parts of it, at best.

I really don't know what to do at this point, maybe my approach is wrong, or it's something else. Whatever it is, I really would appreciate if someone could lead me onto the right path.

Comment: You should say only "divisible". "Divisible without remainder" is redundant.

Comment: Hint: $x^{2m+3}+1 = (x^{2m+3}-x^{2m+1})+(x^{2m+1}+1)$

Comment: Put $\,m = -1\,$ in the linked **Factor Theorem**. $\ \ $

Comment: @Anne That is one form of the Factor Theorem - see the Theorem in the linked dupe.

Comment: @Bill ok sorry for my spam, I deleted it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

$$x^{2m+3} + 1 = x^{2m+1} + 1 + (x + 1)(x^{2m+2} - x^{2m+1})$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

We have the direct factorization
$$
x^n + 1 =(x+1)(1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \ldots + x^{n-1})
$$
which can be checked by expanding the right-hand side and noting the cascading cancellations. (We are using that $n$ is odd because the sign on the term with exponent $n-1$ needs to be positive.)

Comment: Just for clarification (since the OP wanted to use induction): The "$\ldots$" in there is where you actually use induction to do the calculation.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).